# Update statement syntax error

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I have the following string which holds the query I want to execute:

```
     query = "UPDATE inventario"
     + " set descripcion = '" + descripcion + "',"
     + " set bodega = '" + bodega + "'"
     + " where codigo = " + codigo;
```

I get an Update statement syntax error but I dont see where is the error. Any help is appreciated. 
columns "descripcion" and "bodega" are text type columns.

Comment: Can you echo the interpreted query? Basically `System.out.println(query);` after you have assigned all the variables; and please - consider using prepared statements.

Comment: This query makes me itch so badly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it's probably because you've got multiple `set` parts instead of using comma separation, and potentially because you don't have quotes around the `codigo` value (if that's another string)... but I'd *strongly* advise you not to create SQL like this anyway, with values directly in the SQL.

Instead, use a prepared statement:

```
String sql = "UPDATE inventario set descripcion=?, bodega=? where codigo=?";
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setString(1, descripcion);
st.setString(2, bodega);
st.setString(3, codigo);
```

Using prepared statements has three immediate benefits:

- It avoids [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) (think about what happens if your description has a quote in it)
- It separates code (SQL) from data (the values)
- It means you avoid conversions for types like datetime, where going via a string representation is a huge potential source of error

Answer (score 2):

Remove extra `SET` on your query.

```
query = "UPDATE inventario"
 + " set descripcion = '" + descripcion + "',"
 + "     bodega = '" + bodega + "'"
 + " where codigo = " + codigo;
```

but that query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Please parameterize your query.
Example,

```
String query = "UPDATE inventario" + 
               "   set descripcion = ?, bodega = ? " + 
               " where codigo = ?";
PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement(query);
prep.setString(1, descripcion);
prep.setString(2, bodega);
prep.setInt(3, codigo);
prep.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: oh crap didnt catch the extra set. Thanks for the pointers. Yes you are right about the sql injection, I will use the prepared statement as pointed out by another person in the thread. Thanks a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

`SET` keyword is needed only once. Multiple columns that are being updated should be separated by commas, as in the below statement.

```
query = "UPDATE inventario"
    + " set descripcion = '" + descripcion + "',"
    + "     bodega = '" + bodega + "'"
    + " where codigo = " + codigo;
```

BTW, it is highly recommended to use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for such operations instead of forming the query like this to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
query = "UPDATE inventario"
    + " set descripcion = ?, bodega = ? "
    + " where codigo = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, descripcion);
ps.setString(2, bodega);
ps.setInt(3, codigo);
int updateCount = ps.executeUpdate();
```